# How to display flags with search API?

Tags: views, 8, search

On Drupal 8, I created on my content a personal flag "I like".

I installed Search API and I created an index view.

I want my content sorted by the number of "likes" received on each node.

How to do this ?

Comment: in search api settings, look for fields tab, find your flag, added, if you do not see it, at the bottom you will se "add more fields" or similar, add your field, then on views, add your sort

Comment: @pinueve I tried that, but it does not work. If I sort, no content is displayed.

Comment: add flag in fields, hide it if you wish, then that flag will be avaliable in sort settings, if you do not see your flag in fields, add a relationship on your flag COUNT, and ofcourse your view must be based on your index, not on content.

Comment: @pinueve It does not work. COUNT is not available in an index view. There is no relationship between flags and content in an index view.